# Get Gson deserialization to Pojo to fail if pojo does not contain field specified in json

Tags: gson

Given the following json file:

```
{
    "validField":"I'm here",
    "invalidField":"I'm not here :-(",
}
```

And Pojo

```
public class Pojo {
    public String validField;
}
```

When I use gson to deserialize the json into Pojo then I would like it to fail on invalidField as it doesn't exist in Pojo.

```
// This should fail but just ignores 'invalidField' property
Pojo pojo = new Gson().fromJson(json, Pojo.class);
```

Any ideas how to get that to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Lacking an alternative I came up with the following.  I'd still love to hear if there is an supported solution.

```
private static void validateAllDataLoaded(JsonElement element, Object returnType, String entryName) throws IOException {

    if (element.isJsonNull()) {
        return;
    }

    if (element.isJsonArray()) {
        checkFieldExists(entryName, returnType);

        for (Object arrayItem : (ArrayList<?>) returnType) {
            for (JsonElement item : element.getAsJsonArray()) {
                validateAllDataLoaded(item, arrayItem, entryName);
            }
        }
    }

    if (element.isJsonObject()) {
        checkFieldExists(entryName, returnType);

        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : element.getAsJsonObject().entrySet()) {
            if (!entry.getValue().isJsonNull() && !entry.getValue().isJsonPrimitive()) {
                validateAllDataLoaded(entry.getValue(), getField(entry.getKey(), returnType), "");
            } else {
                validateAllDataLoaded(entry.getValue(), returnType, entry.getKey());
            }
        }
    }

    if (element.isJsonPrimitive()) {
        checkFieldExists(entryName, returnType);
    }
}

private static void checkFieldExists(String entryName, Object returnType) throws IOException {
    if (entryName.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    Field[] fields = returnType.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    boolean exists = Arrays.asList(fields).stream().filter(f -> f.getName().equals(entryName)).count() == 1;

    if (!exists) {
        throw new IOException("JSON element '" + entryName + "' is not a field in the destination class " + returnType.getClass().getName());
    }
}

private static Object getField(String entryName, Object returnType) throws IOException {
    if (entryName.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    Field field;
    try {
        field = returnType.getClass().getDeclaredField(entryName);
        field.setAccessible(true);

        return field.get(returnType);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
}
```